# Angular2 CanActivate guard for all routes except one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know that we can group routes located in one module. Like that:

```
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
          { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
          { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ],
      }
```

But I should add that guard to each module's routing file. And I have many of them.

I want that the user can not go to any route except one (login route) if he is not authorized.

What is the right way to add guard to all of them??

Answer (score 12):

You can use a componentless empty path parent route with the guard

```
{ path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard],  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
      { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
      { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
    ],
  }
}
```

and in the guard check if the user is logged in.
If not logged in and the current route is `login` then still allow it.

Comment: What if all child routes in other files?? All modules have their own routing files.

Comment: That should still work. I haven't used that myself yet. If it doesn't work, you can try to add the guard also to `canActivateChild`.

Comment: What is the point of the inner componentless empty path? Why not just add the children to the outer path directly? Besides why would you use canActivate instead of canActivateChildren?

Comment: The point of the inner `''` is to make it the default route. The componentless root route is to be able to add `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` to only a single route and affect all routes.