# How to make all non-child routes guarded?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-router-guards

I have created a routing module in my angular 6 application (**app.routing.ts**). I have added multiple routes to my application, but haven't used the `child` directive anywhere for my routes (bad practice yes, but now I have added dynamic routes as well on another part of my application and don't want to change the entire structure, as it would take a very long time to do so).

I wanted to know if there was a way I could globally use `canActivate: [AuthGuardService]` (which checks if user is logged in) for all my routes except the root. I have checked out a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873060/angular2-canactivate-guard-for-all-routes-except-one) but the guard doesn't seem to work properly and still loads the page. (Maybe it's because I don't have any child routes).

Also, I think that method also may not be the best way because in that case the the Guard (consumed layer) is able to know which layer is consuming it's methods (which imo is not the best approach for the mvc pattern, granted what I have done with the routing module isn't pretty either). Is there a way to achieve this in a cleaner manner?

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'search/:id',
    component: GlobalSearchComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'reset',
    component: ResetPasswordComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'knowledge-base/create',
    component: KnowledgeBaseCreateComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'knowledge-base/detail/:id',
    component: KnowledgeBaseDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'knowledge-base/edit/:id',
    component: KnowledgeBaseEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'projects/detail/:id',
    component: ProjectDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'projects/create',
    component: ProjectCreateComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**authguard.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';

/**
* This injector provides the auth-guard service throughout the application.
*/
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

/**
* The auth guard service is used to prevent unauthenticated users from
* accessing restricted routes, it's used in app.routing.ts to protect the home
* page route
*/
export class AuthGuardService {
  /**
  * The constructor initializes the ToastrService & TranslatePipe in the component.
  */
  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService,
    private translate: TranslatePipe,
    private router: Router) { }
  /**
   * This method checks if the user is authorized to access a certain route.
   *
   * @param  route
   * @param  state
   * @return
   */
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (this.router.url !== '/') {
        let error = this.translate.transform("generic[responses][error][401]");
        this.toastr.warning(error);
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean way to achieve it would be to wrap them in `children` of one route. You said that you are aware of that but you also mentioned that it would cause you to change the whole structure - which is not the case. You probably thought of using `loadChildren` which would in fact cause a bigger change. Here's an example of wrapping your `knowledge-base` route using `children`

```
  {
    path: 'knowledge-base',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: 'knowledge-base/create',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'create',
          component: KnowledgeBaseCreateComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'detail/:id',
          component: KnowledgeBaseDetailComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'edit/:id',
          component: KnowledgeBaseEditComponent
        }
    ]
  }
```

This is everything you have to change, basically just wrap it in `children`. You can apply this approach to other routes as well. Or if you want to use `RouterGuard` only once, you could create something like `path: 'main'`, and wrap everything there

Comment: Actually that's a valid point. Also, the dynamic routes aren't being added if I don't let access to a specific route so they would be inaccessible anyway. Simply encapsulating everything in `children` of the root did solve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per the best practices, you should organize your routes hierarchically and use the children to nest the child routes/components. Route Guards also works in the same way, that's why we have canActivateChild guard.

You can still refactor your routing to only have the parent-child (nesting) relationship and use canActivateChild guard. And I think changing this would not be a major impact. If you do lazy loading and separate routes in modules then it might become a big change.

```
canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
    Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
       return this.canActivate(route, state);
}

{ path: 'servers',  canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], component: ServersComponent,  children: [
      { path: ':id', component: ServerComponent, resolve: { server: ServerResolver } },
      { path: ':id/edit', component: EditServerComponent, canDeactivate: [canDeactivateGuard] }
]}
```

Comment: Agreed, that's pretty much something I had to learn the hard way unfortunately, when I started off on the project I had little (if any) info at all about how to properly use angular routing. When I started to understand what impact this would have I was already way deep into my application, and had to improvise from there on